# Define target directory with flag in `scp` or `rsync` (like `cp -t`)

Tags: bash, rsync, cp, scp

Since I'm often copying a varying number of specific files to a (rather convoluted) destination directory over the network, my life would be so much easier if I could use `cp`'s `-t` flag: With it, you can specify the target directory "at the beginning"—and not as the final argument.

That way, I could `CTRL-R` to my copy command and then `CTRL-W` the previously copied files, all the while leaving the (complex) setup and destination destination system and directory no matter how many files there were earlier.

But I can't find any fitting flags, neither for `scp` nor for `rsync`. (I'd use either, if one of them offered this option.)

Do either `scp` or `rsync` offer anything akin to `cp -t`?

In my desperation, I've even toyed around with `bash`'s history control, the argument extraction mechanisms in particular: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible to specify ranges in the form of "the *x*-th argument to the last-but-one", which I would need since I don't always have the number of arguments (unless I count…).

Comment: Mount the remote destination via sshfs and use `cp` with your `-t` flag :)

Comment: Write your command using variables, then just change the variable value and recall the (unchanged) command. `f='a b'` and `scp ... $f ... ` then `f='c d e'` and recall (assuming no whitespace in filenames). But a small function is best, as in answer by Olorin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can define a function that wraps around `scp`:

```
scpt () {
    scp "$@" user@host:/some/convoluted/path
}
```

And then do

```
scpt file1
scpt /dir1/file2
```

Also, with history interaction, you can get the last argument of the previous `scp` command with `!scp:$`, so you could also do:

```
scp /dir1/file2 !scp:$
```

(since the target directory is usually the last)

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the "easiest" way to solve all my troubles. I hadn't thought of using `!scp:$`; not sure if it's universal enough in my case, but still good advice!